# C# Load a date from a string into a datetimepicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I'm trying to update an old c# program that I inherited along the way.  Not big changes, just adding some new fields etc.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Specifically I'm trying to read a date time from an SQL Table and insert it into a DateTimePicker so the user can read / modify it on the screen.

I have tried a few different ways to do this but the code below seems like the most sensible.

I have read the date time string into a datetime variable from my SQL database.

I can display the value in a message box no problem but when I try and load it into the dateTimePicker control I get an exception.

The date displayed in the message box looks like this. 24/06/2015 12:00:00 AM 
(Australian Date format is correct and I don't care what the time is)

"Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"
_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699

```
while (sqlDR.Read())
{
    this.textBoxFixedAmountStreetNumber.Text = sqlDR["lStreetNumber"].ToString() + sqlDR["sStreetNumberSuffix"].ToString();
    this.textBoxFixedAmountStreetName.Text = sqlDR["sStreet"].ToString();
    this.textBoxFixedAmountSuburb.Text = sqlDR["sTown"].ToString();
    DateTime dateString = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDR["dFixedAmountEndDate"].ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("dFixedAmountEndDate=" + dateString, "Debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    this.dateTimePickerFixedAmountEndDate.Value = dateString;
}
```

I'm probably the worlds oldest newbie because I do mostly sysadmin and never get to concentrate on a single programing language. :)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong is much appreciated.

Thanks
David

Comment: What is the data type of the `dFixedAmountEndDate` column in the database?

Comment: The datatype is datetime

Comment: Then why are you converting the `DateTime` to a `String` and then back to a `DateTime`?  Just assign the original `DateTime` to the `Value` property: `this.dateTimePickerFixedAmountEndDate.Value = (DateTime) sqlDR["dFixedAmountEndDate"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is bad:

```
DateTime dateString = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDR["dFixedAmountEndDate"].ToString());
```

This is its replacement:

```
DateTime fixedAmountEndDate = (DateTime) sqlDR["dFixedAmountEndDate"];
```

Never convert to a string when you don't have to, and use names that make sense.

However, if you're getting `"Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"` - That's a `NullReferenceException`.  Chances are that one of your SQL fields is nullable in the database and contains a null value.  You need to test for that condition explicitly, as a `DateTime` can't be nullable, and neither can [`DateTimePicker.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx).

```
if (sqlDR["dFixedAmountEndDate"] == DBNull.Value)
    // do something.  Perhaps hide the field, etc.
```

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested. It makes sense not to convert from a date to a string and back to a date just for fun.  However I still get the error. "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" when the line that assigns the value to the datetimepicker is executed.

Comment: Yep, then you probably have a null.  Either that, or you don't have a valid reference to the picker control.  Do some debugging.  Set a breakpoint and step through it.  The problem should be obvious once you see what the values are.

Comment: The date field in the data base does allow nulls although the current record I'm processing isn't null.  I don't have valid data for all the rows yet so that is why I choose to allow nulls.  I'll try changing it to not null and put a dummy value in like 01/01/1900.  Thanks for your ideas.  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I set the date filed in my sql table to "not null" and set all the dates to 1900 and this didn't help either.  In desperation I deleted the field from my form and created it again with the same name and did a rebuild of the solution.  Now it works!  I think the last straw was that the field name was screwed up somewhere.  It certainly looks much more professional now with out the dates going through string variables and probably less likely to have trouble in future with the data type set to not null.  So all good now.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var date_as string = "24/06/2015 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime date ;

DateTime.TryParse(d, out date);
// date now holds your date
```

---

**Edit**:
As other comments and Matt's answer suggest, you don't really need to parse a string (so the above even though correct, is probably not what you want).

If you do that you can use the `bool result = DateTime.TryParse(d, out date);` and if the result is `false` assign a fake date (or better, when you define date, you can do: `DateTime date = new DateTime();` so if the parsing fails, you'll still have a valid date.

You can achieve the same by testing for null if you go with the other approach. Either way, you should be aware of the perils :)

Comment: If you're talking about this: `"Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699`, it means the parsing failed (miserably). you can have a `bool result = DateTime.TryParse(d, out date)` , and see if it succeeded or not as well. But the above worked on my machine. What time zone you in? Same as input date time, or different?0

Comment: Yes everything is done in the one time zone.  (Australian Eastern Standard Time) which is UTC +10